# how to make that node still moving while transferring data?

Tags: omnet++

I'm working on the veins example in Omnetpp.

In the veins Omnetpp example, I already run the Erlangen simulation. While transferring data, I noticed that all nodes were stopped & continue moving after finish transferring data to RSU.

My question is, how to make that node still moving while transferring data? Is it possible?

This is because, I want to know the percentage the data was sent according to the velocity of a node. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

The [Veins FAQ](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/) has an entry on this: the simulation time does not advance while the GUI shows an animation.

Note, however, that this does not mean that the car has stopped. In discrete event simulation, wall clock time is very much different from simulation time. In other words, the fact that the simulation is running much slower (or pauses) does not mean that simulated nodes slow down (or pause).

It is important to know that **simulation time** is very different from **wall clock time**. Let's assume that your simulation model triggers two events ("sunrise" and "sunset") per simulated day, 365 sunrises per year. If you execute this simulation model on a bad computer, you will still be able to simulate thousands of sunrises and sunsets (thousands of days in simulation time) within a few milliseconds (of "real" or wall clock time). If you execute this model on a much better computer, you might even be able to simulate not thousands but millions of days (simulation time) within a few milliseconds (wall clock time). The fact that more seconds of simulation time pass for each second of wall clock time does not mean that somehow your simulated years have become shorter; you are still simulating 365 sunrises per simulated year. This is true even if you suspend the computer that is executing the simulation (closing the lid of your laptop) and then later resume the computer. Your simulation model will be completely unaffected.

If we extend this to the example of simulated cars moving in your simulation it should now be clear that it does not matter how fast you can see the cars move on your screen, they will always be driving at the same speed (let's say 13 m/s). On a fast computer you see them move fast. On a slow computer you see them move slow. While OMNeT++ animates method calls you do not see them move at all. Still, their speed does not change.

Comment: in that case, can i change or edit the simulation time? thank for answering chistoph.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: you said that, "in discrete event simulation, wall clock time is very much different from simulation time. In other words, the fact that the simulation is running much slower (or pauses) does not mean that simulated nodes slow down (or pause). "  i do not understand about that . can you explain more? TQ

Comment: I've tried amending the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Christoph.